# Content provider to open images in external app does not work

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-contentprovider

I want to open images which are saved within my app, in an external image viewer app.

Because the images are stored in the (private) app directory, I use a content provider.

Here is the code of my content provider:

```
[ContentProvider(new string[] { "com.company.myapp" })]
    public class CustomContentProvider : ContentProvider
    {
        public static readonly string AUTHORITY = "com.company.myapp";
            public static readonly Android.Net.Uri CONTENT_URI = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("content://" + AUTHORITY);

        public CustomContentProvider()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine ("Custom Content Provider Initialized");
        }


        public override int Delete (Android.Net.Uri uri, string selection, string[] selectionArgs)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException ();
        }

        public override string GetType (Android.Net.Uri uri)
        {
            var mimeType = MimeTypeHelper.GetMimeType(uri.ToString());
                return mimeType;
        }

        public override Android.Net.Uri Insert (Android.Net.Uri uri, ContentValues values)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException ();
        }

        public override bool OnCreate ()
        {
            return true;
        }

        //DOES NOT GET CALLED ON MOST DEVICES
        public override ParcelFileDescriptor OpenFile(Android.Net.Uri uri, string mode)
        {
            string fileName = uri.ToString ().Substring (CONTENT_URI.ToString ().Length);

            System.Console.WriteLine (fileName + " - File to open in external app");
            if (System.IO.File.Exists (fileName)) {
                return ParcelFileDescriptor.Open(new Java.IO.File(fileName), ParcelFileMode.ReadOnly);
            }

            return null;
        }

        public override Android.Database.ICursor Query (Android.Net.Uri uri, string[] projection, string selection, string[] selectionArgs, string sortOrder)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException ();
        }

        public override int Update (Android.Net.Uri uri, ContentValues values, string selection, string[] selectionArgs)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException ();
        }

    }
```

To open the image in an external image viewer app, I use the following code:

```
string fullFilePath = await DataLayer.Instance.GetFilePath (clickedItem.Path);

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, Android.Net.Uri.Parse (CustomContentProvider.CONTENT_URI + fullFilePath));
intent.SetFlags (ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
intent.SetFlags (ActivityFlags.NewTask);
intent.SetFlags (ActivityFlags.ClearWhenTaskReset);

Activity.StartActivity (intent);
```

The problem is that it works on all devices.

The method override ParcelFileDescriptor OpenFile(Android.Net.Uri uri, string mode) does not always get called.

Does someone know how to solve this?

**UPDATE**

Tested it one several versions of Android:

- Emulator API 16 - succeeded
- Emulator API 17 - failed
- Device API 17 - failed
- Emulator API 21 - failed

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

Needed to set the "Exported" property explicit to true

In Xamarin.Android:

```
[ContentProvider(new string[] { "com.company.myapp" }, Exported = true)]
```

In "native" Android:

```
<provider android:name=".CustomContentProvider" android:authorities="com.company.myapp" android:exported="true" />
```